# Subtract two date time in CSV Column

Tags: python, json, csv

```
{
"First Name": "Jonathan",
"Last Name": "Thomas",
"Marital Status": "married or civil partner",
"Sex": "Male",
"Age (Years)": 46,
"Retired": true,
"Distance Commuted to Work (miles)": 13.72,
"Employer Company": "Begum-Williams",
"Dependants": 1,
"Yearly Salary (\u00c2\u00a3)": 54016,
"Yearly Pension (\u00c2\u00a3)": 0,
"Address Street": {
  "Address Street": "00 Wheeler wells",
  "Address City": "Chapmanton",
  "Address Postcode": "L2 7BT"
},
"Credit Card Number": {
  "Credit Card Number": "1234567891011121",
  "Credit Card Start Date": "08/12",
  "Credit Card Expiry Date": "11/26",
  "Credit Card CVV": 000,
  "Bank IBAN": "GB37UMCO54540228728019"
},
"Vehicle Make": {
  "Vehicle Make": "Nissan",
  "Vehicle Model": "ATS",
  "Vehicle Year": 1996,
  "Vehicle Type": "Coupe"
}
```

I have customer data that headers order written randomly. The JSON requirement of the project is above order. So I write a code below to put the correct order and convert to types.

```
l = []

with open("userdata.csv", 'r') as data_file:

    reader = csv.reader(data_file)
    headers = next(reader)
    for reader_row in reader:
        d = {}
        
        d[headers[11]] = str(reader_row[11])
        d[headers[13]] = str(reader_row[13])
        d[headers[14]] = str(reader_row[14])
        d[headers[18]] = str(reader_row[18])
        d[headers[3]] = int(reader_row[3])
        d[headers[16]] = bool(reader_row[16]
        d[headers[4]] = float(reader_row[4])
        d[headers[5]] = str(reader_row[5])
        d[headers[10]] = int(reader_row[10]) if reader_row[10] else None 
        d[headers[17]] = int(reader_row[17])
        d[headers[15]] = int(reader_row[15])
        d[headers[0]]={'Address Street': str(reader_row[0]),
                       'Address City': str(reader_row[1]),
                       'Address Postcode': str(reader_row[2])
                       }
        d[headers[8]]={'Credit Card Number': str(reader_row[8]),
                       'Credit Card Start Date': str(reader_row[6]),
                       'Credit Card Expiry Date': str(reader_row[7]),
                       'Credit Card CVV': int(reader_row[9]),
                       'Bank IBAN' : str(reader_row[12])
                       }
        d[headers[19]]={'Vehicle Make': str(reader_row[19]),
                        'Vehicle Model': str(reader_row[20]),
                        'Vehicle Year': int(reader_row[21]),
                        'Vehicle Type': str(reader_row[22])
                        }
        l.append(d)
    print(d)
```

Then I want to save a JSON file for any customers that have more than 10 years between their start and end date.

```
with open("remove_ccard.json", 'w', encoding='utf-8') as remove: 
    json.dump([d for d in l if d['Credit Card Expiry Date'[-2:]] - d['Credit Card Start Date'[-2:]] > 10], remove)
```

But I get an error on that line, could you help me to fix on my last code, or just guide me on which part I am writing wrong?

```
start_date = []
end_date = []

start_date_single = datetime.strptime(reader_row[6],"%m/%y")
start_date.append(start_date_single)
end_date_single = datetime.strptime(reader_row[7],"%m/%y")
end_date.append(end_date_single)

import json
difference = []
zip_object = zip(end_date, start_date)
with open("remove_ccard.json", 'w', encoding='utf-8') as remove: 
    for end_date, start_date in zip_object:
        difference.append(end_date-start_date)
    for i in difference:
        json.dump([d for d in l if (i) > 10*365.25], remove)

# I WROTE THAT CODE BUT I GET 'datetime.datetime' object is not iterable,
```

I still get an error. Could you help me?

Comment: Show a few lines of `userdata.csv` that work with your code to use as input.

Comment: I also hope that isn't Jonathan Thomas' real credit card information...

Answer (score 1):

Use datetime instead

```
from datetime import datetime

#Replacing d['Credit Card Expiry Date'[-2:]] - d['Credit Card Start Date'[-2:]] > 10
start_date = datetime.strptime(d['Credit Card Start Date'],"%m/%y")
end_date = datetime.strptime(d['Credit Card Expiry Date'],"%m/%y")
```

When you subtract them you get the difference in days. The last part of your code will then be

```
with open("remove_ccard.json", 'w', encoding='utf-8') as remove: 
    json.dump([d for d in l if end_date - start_date > 10*365.25], remove)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I faced error "strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Series" should we write a for loop to reach each item singly.

Comment: In case Python interprets it as pandas Series, then you would use `d['Credit Card Start Date'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, "%y/%m"))`

Comment: Ok I fixed this error but get other one on the dump json file. "'>' not supported between instances of 'datetime.timedelta' and 'float'"

Comment: Wrap them in `(your_value).days > 365.25*10`

Comment: Could you check the new edited question?

Comment: Will you ever be interested in keeping those with less than 10 years difference? Otherwise it would be best to avoid adding the object in the array in the first place

Answer (score 0):

convert string to datetime

```
from datetime import datetime
start = "08/12"
end = "11/26"
date_time_obj1 = datetime.strptime(start, '%m/%y')
date_time_obj2 = datetime.strptime(end, '%m/%y')
c = date_time_obj1 - date_time_obj2
```

Comment: Could you check the new edited question?

Comment: u can use `for end_date, start_date in zip(end_date, start_date)`  or  `new_list = list(zip_object)` then `for first, second in new_list:`